# can someone assist on how to write this?

Tags: tables

Or use the multicol package and create multi-row columns and
multi-column rows. You can become creative and do this^3[image]

Comment: what is your actual question? It appears to be about tables but then mentions multicol which is unrelated to tables, and you have tagged it as {math-mode} but it doesn't appear to be about math at all??

Comment: my question is from the 2nd bullet point, when i tried to write  it, i cant fit within the screen because it is in math mode. and its difficult for me to make the last table title with only 2 colums.

Comment: No _nothing_ in your question mentions math mode or fitting the width or anything. You should show a small complete example tex code that you tried, and say what is wrong with the output or what error you got, and someone will help.

Comment: if you were to write the 2nd bullet point and the table below it, how would you do it?

Comment: That is a tex document, do you not have the source?

Comment: it is practice from class

Comment: well just asking someone here to do your homework is probably not what is expected.

Comment: Please be aware that the statement "Or use the multicol package and create multi-row columns and multi-column rows"  is not correct. The `\multicolumn` command to create a table cell that spans two columns does not need any additional package, the `\multirow` command that creates a cell twat spans two rows does need the `multirow` package. The `multicol` package that is mentioned in the quoted sentence is not related to tables at all but helps to typeset text in two or more columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest you start with a basic tutorial such as

https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-08

But

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Title}\\
\hline
Text&Text&Text\\
\hline
Text&Text&Text\\
\hline
Text&Text&Text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: Can you do my homework too? :)

Answer (score 7):

For the seconde tabular, I suggest `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}[hvlines,corners=NW] % NW : north-west
     & \Block{1-2}{Title} \\
Text & Text & Text \\
Text & Text & Text \\
Text & Text & Text \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: +1: This is probably too advanced for the teacher of the class :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Maybe. To be on the safe side I just provided a very basic solution which does with a few primitives, no complex aligns/tabular-environments. :-)

Answer (score 2):

With the 2nd bullet-point I recommend altogether avoiding the complexity of tabular-environments for the sake of straightforward `\hbox`- and `\vbox`- and `\hrule`- and `\vrule`-nesting.  :-)   (Btw: I'd be glad and thankful about a hint about how to do it this way but without using any (box-)register.)

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newbox\scratchbox
\begin{document}
\hbox{%
  \vbox{%
    \hbox{\vphantom{\strut Title}}%
    \hrule
    \hbox{%
      \vrule
      \vbox{%
        \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
        \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
        \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
      }%
    }%
    \hrule
  }%
  \vbox{%
    \hbox{%
      \vrule
      \vbox{%
        \hrule
        \hbox{%
          \vbox{%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
          }%
          \vrule
          \vbox{%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
            \hbox{\kern\tabcolsep\strut text\kern\tabcolsep}%
          }%
        }%
        \setbox\scratchbox=\lastbox
        \hbox to\wd\scratchbox{\hfill\strut Title\hfill}%
        \hrule
        \box\scratchbox
        \hrule
      }%
      \vrule
    }%
  }%
}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

The statement about multicol-package is somewhat weird because that package is not about tables.
I suppose the statement should be about the `\multicolumn`-command  or about the package [multi**row**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow):

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Title}\\
\hline
\multirow{3}*{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}text\\text\\text\\\end{tabular}}&
\multirow{3}*{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}text\\text\\text\\\end{tabular}}&
\multirow{3}*{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}text\\text\\text\\\end{tabular}}\\
&&\\
&&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*3{c<{text}|}}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Title}\\
\hline&&\\&&\\&&\\\hline\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

is considerably shorter, but the requirement of using some fancy multi...-thing would not be fulfilled.

Comment: I would tend to recommend the exact opposite—I would assume that the data is meant to be a tabular presentation, and while you *can* build things up manually with boxes, rules and glue, you lose any semantic markup.

Comment: @DonHosek If the question did not aim at getting one's homework done by someone else I would definitely share your point of view. :-)